# ¿Alguien me propria explicar como cargar componentes asíncronos de vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, asincronismo

Ya estuve buscando por varios lados y no encuentro un ejemplo practico de como cargar componentes dinámicos mediante larvel mix.

En la documentacion de vue js dice que solo debes de modificar require locual quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```
Vue.component('async-example' , function ( resolve, reject ) 
{ 
  setTimeout ( function () 
      { 
         // Pasar la definición del componente a la resolución resuelta de 
                devolución de llamada     
      ({       
          template: '<div> ¡Soy asincrónico! </ Div>'     
       })   
      }, 1000 ) 
})
```

Pero el copilador que viene por defecto en laravel (webpack) no compila. Tengo entendido que esto se debe a que necesita una configuración especial para procesar estos archivos que cargaran de forma asíncrona y dinámica.

Si alguien me puede pasar un ejemplo practico donde pueda manosear el código se lo agradecería. No importa que este en ingles.

Comment: ¿Has probado lo que se dice en esta respuesta: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1249#issuecomment-335112415?

Comment: Que error te da el compilador o donde te falla exactamente?